# Plotting binomial proportions on a box & whiskers plot using R

Tags: r, data-visualization, boxplot

Apologies in advance - I'm a bit of a newbie with R but I've been Google-ing this for weeks and I haven't found a straight answer.

**The problem**

Basically, I'm looking to plot proportions with their confidence intervals on a box and whiskers plot using the R environment.

i.e. Plot the results of binom.test(100,1000) and binom.test(125,1000)

What is the best package (I don't have a preference either way) and way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This really does look to be more appropriate to an [r] tagged question in SO but there seems to be a surprisingly wide degree of tolerance for such questions in CV, so here goes. The answer also assumes you did not really want to use the existing `boxplot()` function which is what would be used to construct a true box-and-whiskers plot (and which doesn't really use binomial CI's, but rather uses the Tukey defined `fivenum()` function ). The plotrix and gplots packages both have what appears to be the same plotCI function;

```
est1 <- binom.test(100,1000) ; est2 <- binom.test(125,1000)
estvals <- rbind( c(est1$estimate, est1$conf.int[1], est1$conf.int[2]),
                  c(est2$estimate, est2$conf.int[1], est2$conf.int[2]))
plotCI(x = c(1,2), estvals[,1], ui=estvals[,3], li=estvals[,2], 
         xlim=c(0.5,2.5), ylim=c(0, 0.15) , xaxt="n", xlab="Groups")
```

The basic function is the `arrows()` plotting function with an argument that splays the points of the arrows to 90 degrees in both directions.